# Xcode 4 Source Editor Not Displaying Text Properly

Tags: xcode4, text-editor

My Xcode has suddenly began to display unreadable text in the source editor. No other apps are affected. It is most notable with white/bright-colored text on a black background but it occurs in every theme.

The text looks like the the background is bleeding through the foreground text characters. It doesn't really look like "the jaggies" that you used to see with bitmapped fonts.

[Here is s side by side comparison](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/837/xcodetextfailure.png/) between Xcode and the terminal using the same orange on black theme, at the same font of Menlo 12. Even in the reduced resolution screen shot, the difference is obvious. On screen, the terminal text display is crisp and easily readable while the Xcode text is barely readable and, as a practical matter, useless.

I don't know when the problem may have started because I haven't been working in Xcode recently. The only change is that I added a second monitor to my dev box but removing the monitor did not resolve the problem.

I tried using the `com.apple.dt.Xcode` defaults to set the anti-aliasing of Xcode to 24 point but that too had no effect.

I'm stumped. My next step will be to reinstall Xcode but I was hoping someone else may have hit this problem before and has a neater resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reinstall of Xcode resolved the issue. Haven't the foggiest why.

### Update:

[This answer over at Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14560/strange-font-behavior-with-external-monitors-on-macbook) might be relevant as well.